# Iterate through list of file in a list for a directory in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filelist

I need to create CMD batch file which should have a predefined list of files, we are keeping eye on certain files, for a particualr directory. I have to iterate through this list and have to produce a result may be in a form of text file that only gives files sizes greater than 1MB.

So for instance if there are files called (a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,d.txt) and have respective lengths 900k,1.1mb,500kb and 1.5MB, then my outout file should look like 
length of file b.txt > 1MB = 1.1 MB
length of file d.txt > 1MB = 1.5MB.

I need help in initializing and storing the file list in an array ,and how can i iterate through the fil list and spit out the result in a txt file.

Comment: The answer below will fail with long filenames. Also, batch math tops out at 2^31 so if you are checking filesizes of that magnitude then you need to say so.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your list of files as parameters to the script, end then use [SHIFT](http://www.computerhope.com/shift.htm) to iterate.

`call batch.cmd a.txt b.txt c.txt`

a skeleton of batch.cmd :

```
:START
IF "%1"=="" GOTO END
REM -- CHECK FILE SIZE HERE
DO STUFF

SHIFT
GOTO START

:END
```

Comment: if it solve your problem, feel free to vote else explain what blocks. Thank's